# ¿Cómo descargar un directorio completo desde un ftp usando cmd?

Tags: windows, ftp, servidor

Buenas tardes.

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:
Cree un servidor FTP en windows (así me lo solicitaron) y el FTP funciona bien de manera general. Mi pregunta es: si dentro del FTP género una carpeta (archivos) y dentro de ella tengo 10 documentos, ¿Cómo puedo descargarla completa?

Sé que puedo entrar a la carpeta y bajar todos los archivos, pero lo que a mi me interesa es bajar el directorio (la carpeta llamada "archivo")

¿Alguien sabe como puedo hacer esto?

Se lo agradecería demasiado.

Pdt: Tanto el FTP como el cliente don equipos Windows, por lo que wget no funciona.

Comment: Has buscado info sobre mget ?: ftp> mget *.*

Comment: Sí, con mget puedo obtener varios (incluso todos) archivos de un directorio de FTP. Pero no el directorio como tal.

Comment: En la lista de comandos para windows, no veo algo que obtenga el path como tal, sería crear un batch y hacer un mkdir, etc

Comment: Pero si hago eso, como le indico cuántos directorios son los directorios que va a descargar para que cree las carpetas necesarias y como le indico el nombre de cada directorio?

Answer (score 1):

como ya lo comentaron la única opción desde cmd es el comando mget, pero no hay un manera de descargar carpetas completas. Tal vez sería una buena opción utilizar un programa cliente ftp como Filezilla o bien el propio Explorador de Windows, para descargar la carpeta completa a una ubicación local en tu equipo.

Comment: exactamente tengo el mismo problema, En mi caso necesito descargarme un directorio remoto a mi pc, y esto va en un script de python que lo ejecuta el administrador de tareas de Windows, y no voy a venir a las 5 de la mañana cuando se ejecute a abrir filezilla